BPMN: How can messages cross sub-process borders?
I need to send messages from within a subprocess. Now I read about the booking example and boundary events to and fro. But I am missing the concept how to pass information into and out of a sub-process.
I know that a call action would open up all possibilities of a complete process with respective pools. But this is not what I want/can do here.
So my sub-process is just a embedded in its parent process.
I can think of different possibilities:
M 1 Actually what I thought of. But I guess the message flow is not allowed to cross sub process boundaries though I do not understand why as it should just be a graphical thing, shouldn't it?
M 2 Sending an escalation from within and a catching boundary one seems overkill, but the only possibility?
Now when I think of the sub-process being folded, what are allowed possibilities then (or might follow)?
M 3 seems to be a default one - though too general and the concrete mechanism is unclear.
M 4 appears to be valid at first sight but from where should it catch the message? Sending within the same pool is not allowed, so actually seems not valid. (Therefore I did not model it in the expanded sub-process.)
M 5 is just like M 2.
So are M 2 and M5 the only valid way(s)? Your thoughts are really appreciated. I think this should be an everyday issue, what do I miss?

